# Задание описать класс "студенческая группа"

Tags: c#

По заданию нужно 
Описать класс "студенческая группа". 
Предусмотреть возможность работы с переменным числом студентов, 
поиска студента по какому-либо признаку (например, по имени,
фамилии, дате рождения), добавления и удаления записей, сортировки по разным полям,   доступа к записи по номеру.

Реализован отдельный класс Student

```
namespace Class1
{
sealed class Student
{
    public Student(string name, string surname, string dateOfBirthday)
    {
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
        DateOfBirthday = dateOfBirthday;
    }

    public void ChangeName(Student student, string name)
    {
        if (student != null && student.Name != name)
        {
            student.Name = name;
        }
    }

    public void ChangeSurname(Student student, string surname)
    {
        if (student != null && student.Name != surname)
        {
            student.Surname = surname;
        }
    }

    public void ChangeDateOfBirthday(Student student, string dateOfBirthday)
    {
        if (student != null && student.Name != dateOfBirthday)
        {
            student.DateOfBirthday = dateOfBirthday;
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string DateOfBirthday { get; set; }
}
}
```

потом класс StudentGroup

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Class1
{
class StudentGroup
{
    List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

    public void AddStudent(string name, string surname, string dateOfBirthday)
    {
        Student student = new Student(name, surname, dateOfBirthday);
        students.Add(student);
    }

    public void RemoveStudent(Student student)
    {
        students.Remove(student);
    }

    public string GetStudent(int id)
    {
        return students[id].Name + " " + students[id].Surname + " " + students[id].DateOfBirthday;
    }

    public void ShowAllStudent()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Все студенты: ");
        foreach (var student in students)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(student.Name + "\t" + student.Surname + "\t" + student.DateOfBirthday);

        }
    }

    public int GetAmount()
    {
        return students.Count;
    }

    public string FindByName(StudentGroup studentGroup, string name)
    {

    }
}
}
```

и в программе

```
using System;

namespace Class1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var studentGroup = new StudentGroup();
        studentGroup.AddStudent("Masha", "Ivanova", "30.07.1986");
        studentGroup.AddStudent("Petya", "Petrov", "28.06.1985");
        studentGroup.AddStudent("Ivan", "Sidorov", "05.09.1987");

        Console.Write("Введите id = ");
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(studentGroup.GetStudent(id));

        Console.Write("Введите имя: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Введите фамилию: ");
        string surname = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Введите дату рождения: ");
        string dateOfBirthday = Console.ReadLine();

        studentGroup.AddStudent(name, surname, dateOfBirthday);
        Console.Write("Введите id = ");
        id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(studentGroup.GetStudent(id));

        studentGroup.ShowAllStudent();
        Console.WriteLine("Общее количество студентов в группе " + studentGroup.GetAmount());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

не могу разобраться, как сделать метод удаления и методы сортировки?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, Вам нужно идти в сторону Связных списков.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

класс студент с реализованный интерфейсом IComparable;

```
sealed class Student:IComparable<Student>
{
    public Student(string name, string surname, string dateOfBirthday)
    {
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
        DateOfBirthday = dateOfBirthday;
    }

    public void ChangeName(Student student, string name)
    {
        if (student != null && student.Name != name)
        {
            student.Name = name;
        }
    }

    public void ChangeSurname(Student student, string surname)
    {
        if (student != null && student.Name != surname)
        {
            student.Surname = surname;
        }
    }

    public void ChangeDateOfBirthday(Student student, string dateOfBirthday)
    {
        if (student != null && student.Name != dateOfBirthday)
        {
            student.DateOfBirthday = dateOfBirthday;
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string DateOfBirthday { get; set; }
    //реализация метода CompareTo интефейса IComparable
    public int CompareTo(Student that)
    {
        return String.Compare(Name, that.Name, System.StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }
}
```

теперь можешь вызывать Sort() у листа студентов, и лист отсортируется по имени

еще можно делегат передать в качестве аргумента методу Sort()

```
  groups.Sort(delegate(Student xStudent, Student yStudent)
        {
            if (xStudent.Surname == null && yStudent.Surname == null) return 0;
            if (xStudent.Surname == null) return -1;
            if (yStudent.Surname == null) return 1;
            return String.Compare(xStudent.Surname, yStudent.Surname, System.StringComparison.Ordinal);
        });
```

еще можно ввести в ступор старенького препода написав тоже самое но с помощью лямбды

```
    groups.Sort(( x,  y) => String.Compare(x.Name, y.Name, StringComparison.Ordinal));
```

Answer (score 3):

Удаление вы уже сделали (метод `RemoveStudent`, там вы используете метод `Remove` класса `List` для удаления элемента по значению). Если хотите удалять не по значению, а по месту в списке, ипользуйте метод [`RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5cw9x18z.aspx). Сортировка осуществляется методом [`Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3da4abas.aspx) класса `List`. Чтобы сообщить методу, как нужно сравнивать объекты класса `Student`, нужно одно из следующих условий:

- класс `Student` должен реализовывать интерфейс [`IComparable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx);
- при вызове [`Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/234b841s.aspx) нужно передавать ему компаратор (класс, реализующий интерфейс [`IComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx));
- при вызове [`Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) нужно передавать ему делегат, сравнивающий объекты класса `Student`.